# Connecting Scala and Play-Slick to AWS MySQL

Tags: mysql, scala, amazon-web-services, playframework-2.0, slick

Having difficulty connecting to AWS MySQL database in a new Scala Play Slick application. I can connect to the database from MySQL Workbench.

application.conf contains:

```
db.default.user=myusername
db.default.password=mypassword
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

The problem may be in db.default.url=

The MySQL Workbench copy JDBC connection string command yields:

```
"jdbc:mysql://sperch-dev.coafgaprx2uf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/?user=myusername"
```

Including the "user=" here as MySQL Workbench suggests seems redundant with db.default.user and anyway I get the error message "[SQLException: No database selected]" with or without it.

Having seen elsewhere the pattern for db.default.url as:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASENAME?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

I tried adding the database name:

```
"jdbc:mysql://sperch-dev.coafgaprx2uf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/sperch-dev?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

That however generates the error message:
"Cannot connect to database [default]"

My db.default.user and db.default.password are the same as the working connection in MySQL Workbench.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you assign your AWS RDS MySQL instance to a Security Group that allows external access? Try connecting to it using the mysql command line tool on your machine and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was, however, able to connect both from the MySQL workbench and the command line tool. The AWS RDS instance is part of a security group that allows my IP. However, when running the Play application locally, it still gives the error: "[SQLException: No database selected]" with the connection parameters specified above and using play-slick.

Comment: Maybe try some other jdbc based product, e.g. SquirreLSQL and see if the connection string works in there..

Answer (score -1):

Remove the Port number and user name from the db.default url.  Below is an example of what works.

```
# Database configuration
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://your-rds-instance.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/DATABASE_SCHEMA_HERE"
db.default.user=user
db.default.pass="password"
```